# how to convert rows as columns and columns as rows in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with multiple columns but there is one column named 'City' and inside 'City' we have multiple (city names) and another column named as 'Complaint type' and having multiple types of complaints inside this, and i have to convert the all unique cities into columns and all unique complaint types as rows.

and there is a 'Unique Key' variable which is assigned to each complaint.

Please help me with the proper codes.

```
df_new=df.pivot_table(index='Complaint Type',columns='City',values='Unique Key')
df_new
```

I did this and worked but is there any other way to do it as it is not clear to me

Comment: Please post sample data so that we can provide possible alternatives. If pivot works, then I wouldn't worry about using another method unless it's purely academic.

Comment: so this should be ok to go right and yes it is giving me the result so ok i got it

Comment: If it's performant and gives you the right results? Yep, you solved the problem and you don't need to do anything further with it. Time to move on to the next piece of code. But if you don't understand why it worked, I encourage you to study it and figure out what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Unique Key` column is not relevant here. Use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df_new = pd.crosstab(df['Complaint Type'], df['City'])
print(df_new)

# Output
City            V  W  X  Y  Z
Complaint Type               
A               0  1  0  0  4
B               5  2  2  3  1
C               0  3  1  0  1
D               2  2  1  2  3
E               0  1  1  1  4
F               2  1  1  0  2
G               0  1  0  0  3
```

If you prefer to use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), you have to use an aggregation function since you have no numeric column:

```
df_new = df.pivot_table(index='Complaint Type', columns='City', aggfunc='size')
print(df_new)

# Output
City            V  W  X  Y  Z
Complaint Type               
A               0  1  0  0  4
B               5  2  2  3  1
C               0  3  1  0  1
D               2  2  1  2  3
E               0  1  1  1  4
F               2  1  1  0  2
G               0  1  0  0  3
```

You should also read [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/15239951)

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng(2023)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Complaint Type': rng.choice(list('ABCDEFG'), 50),
                   'City': rng.choice(list('VWXYZ'), 50)})
```